# InfoPath 2007 append text like MOSS multiline

Tags: infopath, multiline-text-field

I have an InfoPath 2007 form with several multiline text fields and I'd like to have newly added text in those fields append to the existing text with a user and time/date stamp as we see in SharePoint multiline text. In a perfect solution I'd have the text box on one view of my form and the "change history" on another view but I can work that out if I can get the append method working.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will have to have 2 multiline text boxes for each case, the first one will be in enabled mode always and will have a default blank value.
2. The second text box will be in read only mode, which will store the text history, user and date timestamp.
3. While saving the form, the textbox2 value should be saved using a concat function, with the existing textbox1 value, the username() function in the formula field and the now() function with additional spaces to bring better readability.
4. Each time the form is saved, the textbox2 value will get appended and should maintain a history of the values entered in textbox1.

Comment: Ahhh... simpler than I thought! I was overcomplicating the problem, thanks for the helpful response!